# How come $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \! e^{-|t|} \, \mathrm{d} t = 2\int_{0}^\infty \! e^{-|t|} \, \mathrm{d} t$?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, even-and-odd-functions

In a text book problem, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \! e^{-|t|} \, \mathrm{d} t$ is said to equal $2\int_{0}^\infty \! e^{-|t|} \, \mathrm{d} t$. I cannot understand how this conclusion is reached.

I may be close to understanding it, but it seems weird and overly simplistic, so it feels like I've made a mistake. It may be because

$$\int_{-n}^n \! x^2 \, \mathrm{d} t = \frac{n^3}{3} - (-\frac{n^3}{3}) = 2\frac{n^3}{3} = 2\int_{0}^n \! x^2 \, \mathrm{d} t$$

but it feels weird and overly simple. Is that really it, or am I missing something crucial?

Comment: The fun part is you don't need to solve the integral in order to confirm it. It would be true for any function that has its variable under modulus.

Comment: Maybe if you _sketched_ the integrand before trying calculus, a plan of attack might suggest itself.

Answer (score 11):

Much much simpler:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)dx + \int_{-\infty}^{0} f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} f(-x)dx $$ 
Since in your case: $$f(-x) = f(x)$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx  =2\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)dx$$

Comment: Please write your integrals properly, the notation $\int f(x)$ is undefined and should be replaced by $\int f(x)dx$ or $\int f(t)dt$ or whichever you like.

Answer (score 5):

Not that the integrand, $\exp(-|t|)$ is an even contious function on $\mathbb R$. There is a fact that for an even function $f(x)$ we have; $$\int_{-a}^{a}f(x)dx=2\int_0^af(x)dx,a>0$$

Here is the plot of integrand:

[image]

Comment: The punchline is of course that for even functions $f(x)$ we have $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx =  \lim_{a \to \infty} \int_{-a}^a f(x) dx = \lim_{a \to \infty} 2 \cdot \int_0^a f(x) dx = 2 \int_0^{\infty} f(x) dx.$$

Comment: @JavaMan: Indeed, your comment makes the answer potent. Thanks.

Comment: Nice combination: hints, graph, and comment! +1